# How can I load value from AngularJS controller to HTML Thymeleaf tag

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf

Can I do:

```
<source th:src="@{{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}}" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

Like this:

```
<source scr="{{videoPaths[$index]}}" type="video/mp4"</source>
```

Or how can I load values from the controller in `th:src`? Can you provide me another way?

Update

```
<li ng-repeat="video in videos">Video-ul: {{$index+1}} >
    <video width="300" controls="controls">
        <source ng-src="{{videoPaths[$index]}}"
                th:src="@{{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}}" type="video/mp4">
        </source>
    </video>
</li>
```

**Update:**

Apparently Thymeleaf it loads the video successfully if I leave the source like this:

```
<source th:src="@{{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}}" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

or

```
<source src="{{videoPaths[$index]}}" th:src="@{{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}}" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

But I receive this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>   - /%7B%7BvideoPathsTh[$index]%7D%7D

I think it's because the server loads the HTML file before Client loads the page and the `AngularJS controller` can't send the values.

Comment: Can you please add controller code, So i will help you

Comment: Videopaths it's just an array of strings

Comment: I updated my post by adding how I need those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not possible...Thanks